# Retrieve Func value>?

Tags: c#, func

I have a following question - if I make instance of class DrawingList(with Func delegate in the constructor) in other class (let's say classA) and user clicks item in
some kind of list or DataGrid  (which belongs to DrawingList class) I would like to set the clicked item data as the value that is returned by func to the class A where the instance of DrawingList was made. Any help, how to retrieve that value?
Sample:

```
public partial class DrawingList : UserControl
{
    public DrawingList( Func<ConnectionData> pass)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PassAction = pass;
    }

    public Func<ConnectionData> PassAction{ get; set; }

    private void List_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        PassAction = () => SelectedRow;          
    }
}

public class A
{
    private ConnectionData _selectedRow;
    public ConnectionData SelectedRow
    {
        get { return _selectedRow; }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRow");
        }
    }

    //here I would like to retrieve Func value
    var drawingList = new DrawingList(() => SelectedRow );//???
}
```

Comment: Its not clear which method/member belongs to which class. Can you fix the code to make it clear? You should probably save the value in some variable and use it later when you create an instance of the `DrawingList` calss.

Comment: Are you saying the DataGrid is bound to a collection of `DrawingList` items?  Is this a WinForm or web app?

Comment: Yes, DataGrid is bound to a collection of DrawingList items and it is WPF application.